# Django: retrieve data for a specific interval

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I am going to build my dashboard. Design of this Dashboard is completed. Now the problem is that I did not understand how to retrieve my sum of data from database (mysql) with a specific interval. for example I want to retrieve revenue of last 15 days? how ??

**models.py**

```
class JaGAnalyticsData(models.Model):
project_management_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
ecommerce_users = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
total_revenue = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
conversion_rate = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
total_transactions = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'ja_g_analytics_data'
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
jga = JaGAnalyticsData.objects.all()   #this line of code will fetch the data from db
context = {'jga':jga}
#html_template = loader.get_template('home/index.html')
#return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
return render(request, 'home/index.html',context)
```

**index.html**

```
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   <h5 style="margin-top:3px " class="card-title text-uppercase text-muted mb-0">Last 
  week</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
  {{% for i in a %}}
   <span style="float: right;" class="h4 font-weight-bold">{{i.total_revenue}}</span>
    {{% end for %}}
     </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You want the total of `total_revenue` that is in `JaGAnalyticsData` model?

Comment: yes Dear @allexiusw, I want the **total_revenue** for a week, month, year

Comment: Look at the @barbaart solution that is enough for your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a `DateField` to your JaGAnalyticsData model you can edit your queryset to get the last 15 days.

Add this to your model:

```
created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And to query the last 15 days you can use:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

jga = JaGAnalyticsData.objects.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.today()-timedelta(days=15))
```

And to calculate the total revenue of these days:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

jga = JaGAnalyticsData.objects.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.today()-timedelta(days=15)).aggregate(Sum('total_revenue'))
```